# Changing <p> value onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have only started to learn JS and I'm a bit stuck.
So I have an HTML code + JS to change the

value but it doesn't work and I have no idea why... Thanks for help ^^

```
    <p class="username">T</p>
    <input type="text" class="usernameValue">
    <button onclick="usernameChange()">Change</button>
```

```js
function usernameChange(){
  var usernameValue = document.querySelector('.usernameValue').value;
  var username = document.querySelector('.username').innerHTML;
  username = usernameValue;
}
```

Oh I'm so dumb, thanks everyone for the help

Comment: @gurvinder372 oh, sorry, I'll update, you can check Codepen to see it

Comment: You're assigning to a string variable and not a node's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a div with a class of username, so add that if it's not in your code.

You misspelled `onclick` inside of `<button onclick="usernameChange()">Change</button>`

You'll also want to capture the element itself rather than a reference to `innerHTML`, and then set the element's innerHTML to your value.

```
var username = document.querySelector('.username');
username.innerHTML = usernameValue;
```

```js
function usernameChange(){
  var usernameValue = document.querySelector('.usernameValue').value;
  var username = document.querySelector('.username');
  username.innerHTML = usernameValue;
}
```

```html
<div class="username"></div>
<input type="text" class="usernameValue">
<button onclick="usernameChange()">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

`username` is not a reference to the actual string. If you want to change the `innerHTML` of the element with class `username` you need to explicitly say so

```
document.querySelector('.username').innerHTML = usernameValue;
```

Also, you have a typo in your html. It should be `onclick`, not `onlick`.

Comment: Well, in some languages that kind of semantic is actually a thing, so I'm not too surprised

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the one string to another, it doesn't update the element's `innerHTML`, you need to do

```
document.querySelector('.username').innerHTML = usernameValue ;
```

You also need to change `onlick` to `onclick`, refer to the demo below.

**Demo**

```js
function usernameChange(){
  var usernameValue = document.querySelector('.usernameValue').value;
  document.querySelector('.username').innerHTML = usernameValue;
}
```

```html
<p class="username" id="username">T</p>
<input type="text" class="usernameValue">
<button onclick="usernameChange()">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be `<button onclick="usernameChange()">Change</button>` not `<button onlick="usernameChange()">Change</button>`

Comment: Correct, but it's not the only mistake!